# Marquee on dynamic changing text

Tags: android, textview, android-animation, marquee

I am using below code to change my textview text after few seconds at runtime.I want to scroll this text as a marquee , but text is not scrolling , it works fine if I set the textview text out side runnable ,but i need to scroll text plus change the text dynamically from string array.

Please suggest.

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (abc.length)-1; i++) {
            final int value = i;
            if(i==(abc.length)-1)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvAddContent.setText(":: " + abc[value].toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

XML code :

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivAdd"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white_font" />
```